# Custom module cannot be found

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

i have the following error

```
Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/mware/jwtVerify' imported from /usr/src/app/routes/projects/projectsRouter.js
```

The thing is, the path is correct, so it is not a problem with my import

```
import jwtVerify from "../../mware/jwtVerify"
```

The module itself is this

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import fs from "fs";

function jwtVerify(req, res, next){
  const jwtkey = fs.readFileSync(process.env.JWT_PUBLIC_KEY);
  if (!req.headers["auth"]) {
    return res.status(401).send("No token provided");
  }
  const token = req.headers["auth"];
  jwt.verify(token, jwtkey, { algorithms: ["RS256"] }, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(418).send("Failed to authenticate token");
    }
    req.decoded = decoded;
    next();
  });
};

module.exports = jwtVerify;
```

And i am not certain what i am doing wrong.

I am currently learning but i did try importing it in brackets and making it a named func (it was an arrow one before) to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're probably just missing `.js`

Comment: yup. well thank you, don't know how i missed this